# How does json String to Object auto conversion works in Spring cloud Stream?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I am looking at this example - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/master/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-product-tracker/src/main/java/kafka/streams/product/tracker/KafkaStreamsProductTrackerApplication.java

Trying to do something similar, but for me it is not working. How does product json string is received as Product Object ?

Answer (score 4):

By default, the deserialization on the inbound KStream is done by Spring Cloud Stream. The default content-type used is `application/json` (equivalent to providing the property: `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.contentType: application/json`). This is why the product json string is properly converted.

You can disable the framework level conversion and let Kafka do that in which case you need to provide the Serdes through properties. In order to enable native deserialization, you can set the property - `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.useNativeDecoding: true`. Then you need to provide the appropriate Serdes. More on all these are here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_message_conversion

Comment: This document has a sample binding as - spring.cloud.stream.kstream.bindings.output3.producer.valueSerde=JsonSerde. Should it be - spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.output3.producer.valueSerde=JsonSerde

Comment: You are correct. It should be `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.....`. Thanks for pointing that out. Will fix it in the docs.

Comment: I created custom Serde - CustomSerde extends JsonSerde<T>  

For some reason - It is not able to load valueSerde for binding but it tries to load default value serde only.  

This fails - cannot convert String to Custom Object. 
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.value.serde: Serdes$StringSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.mysql-kstream-member.consumer.valueSerde: CustomSerde
  
This works - spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.value.serde: CustomSerde

Comment: It seems valueSerde is working for any message sent within spring-cloud-stream application but not working for a message received from external application. Even though Kafka-streams binding is there, it ignores it and look for binder default value serve.

Comment: Hi, The value Serde per input binding should work. Any chance you can create a simple sample application where you reproduce this issue and file a bug report on github? We will take a look.

Comment: Sure, I will do that.

Comment: Tried - `code spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.input1.consumer.valueSerde: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerde`                 got error - java.lang.IllegalStateException: No type information in headers and no default type provided. ----> Is this correct way, how do I pass type ?

Comment: If its json, i suggest simply not providing any Serdes on the binding, and  let the binder do the deserialization. Make sure that `nativeDecoding` is disabled (which is the default). That way, scst will automatically try to deserialize using a json converter if the incoming object is json friendly. If I can see a sample,  I will take a look.

Comment: I got this working, looks like AvroMapper was doing some issue. I removed the mapping logic to use AvroMapper and it worked. Not sure what it is.